# Using iScroll with JQM and dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, append, iscroll4

I am trying to implement iScroll into my HMTL5 game using jQuery. I can't seem to get it to work? I have followed the guide here: http://www.gajotres.net/using-iscroll-with-jquery-mobile/

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(".example-wrapper").html("");

    var html = '<ul data-role="listview">';
    for(i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        html += '<li><a href="#">link '+i+'</a></li>';
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    $(".example-wrapper").append(html);
    $(".example-wrapper").iscrollview("refresh");
});
```

The difference in the project is that it uses trigger and I am using append... I can't seem t get the connection?

My example is on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmansa/952NJ/23/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iScroll dynamically generates a div which contains scrollable elements, that div has class `iscroll-content`.

```
<div class="example-wrapper" data-iscroll></div>
```

Becomes

```
<div class="example-wrapper" data-iscroll>
  <div class="iscroll-content"></div>
</div>
```

So when you use `$(".example-wrapper").html("")` you remove all contents of the div, instead, you should use `$(".example-wrapper .iscroll-content").html("")` to clear previous contents/elements.

Also, you need to append new elements to `iscroll-content`, and then *refresh* both, `listview()` and `.iscrollview()`.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function () {
    $(".example-wrapper .iscroll-content").html("");

    var html = '<ul data-role="listview">';
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        html += '<li><a href="#">link ' + i + '</a></li>';
    }
    html += '</ul>';

    $(".example-wrapper .iscroll-content").append(html);
    $("[data-role=listview]").listview();
    $(".example-wrapper").iscrollview("refresh");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/y9JHs/)**